# Can't create linked server to Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I followed all the instructions I could find:

1. Installed latest Snowflake 64bit ODBC driver to my SQL Server VM
2. Created system dsn for it (filled in User, Server, Database, Schema, Warehouse, Role and Tracing fields)
3. In SQL server, for the MSDASQL linked server provider, enabled following parameters: Nested queries, Level zero only, Allow inprocess, Supports 'Like' Operator
4. Created linked server following instructions

   - Provider=Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC drivers
   - Data source: name of system DSN I created
   - Security:
   - mapped local login 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' to remote username and password (they work when I connect to Snowflake via web browser)
   - click 'Be made using the login's current security context'
     when clicking ok, I get the following error

[image: Error message]

Comment: Error seems to be pretty clear here. *"Incorrect username or password was specified."*

Comment: It does seem straightforward, but I'm using the same values for the remote uname/pwd as I use to login to Snowflake on the web

Answer (score 0):

In the security tab of the linked server:

1. you have mapped 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' (is this the sql service account?) to remote username and password.
2. For any other login not in the list you have selected **Be made using the login's current security context**

You connect to sql server using a windows login or a sql server login. Assume you either use domainxyz\rick  or username: sqlrick and password: rick1212.
When you try to use the linked server, both possible logins (domainxyz/rick or sqlrick) are not mapped to a remote[snowflake] username and password. So sql server passes through the current security context which is either your domainxyz/rick token or the sqlrick username&password. Both do fail for an external server(can they even work?).

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine

**Be made using the login's current security context**
Specify that a connection will be made using the current security context of the login for logins not defined in the list. If connected to the local server using Windows Authentication, your windows credentials will be used to connect to the remote server. If connected to the local server using SQL Server Authentication, login name and password will be used to connect to the remote server. In this case a login with the exact same name and password must exist on the remote server.

You could either map your login to the remote snowflake username&password, or choose

For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:
Be made using **this** security context and fill in the username&password for snowflake in the boxes.

```
/*
snowflake server=xyz12345.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com
snowflake user= testuser
snowflake password = Testuser1
*/

--system DSN for snowflake named SNOWFLAKEDSN [SnowflakeDSIIDriver, User: testuser, Server:xyz12345.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com, Database:DEMO_DB, Tracing:4 (default)]
--Note: Attempting any of the commands with a wrong password could lock temporarily the snowflake account. tread carefully


--snowflake without linked server
--openrowset using dsn
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'DSN=SNOWFLAKEDSN;UID=testuser;PWD=Testuser1', 'select cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar(100)) as tablename from demo_db.information_schema.tables');

--openrowset using dsn2 , format= provider, DSN;uid;password, query
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'SNOWFLAKEDSN';'testuser';'Testuser1', 'select cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar(100)) as tablename from demo_db.information_schema.tables');


--openrowset without dsn
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'DRIVER=SnowflakeDSIIDriver;SERVER=xyz12345.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com;UID=testuser;PWD=Testuser1', 'select cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar(100)) as tablename from demo_db.information_schema.tables');

GO


--linked server using DSN
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SNOWFLAKE_WITH_DSN', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'SNOWFLAKEDSN';
 /*every login of the sql instance connects to snowflake as testuser*/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SNOWFLAKE_WITH_DSN',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'testuser',@rmtpassword='Testuser1';


--linked server without DSN, name of linked server is SNOWFLAKE_WITHOUT_DSN
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SNOWFLAKE_WITHOUT_DSN', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @provstr=N'DRIVER=SnowflakeDSIIDriver;SERVER=xyz12345.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com';
 /*every login of the sql instance connects to snowflake as testuser*/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SNOWFLAKE_WITHOUT_DSN',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'testuser',@rmtpassword='Testuser1';


--linked server without DSN, hardcoded snowflake creds in the provider string (at own risk)
/*
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SNOWFLAKE_WITHOUT_DSN_HARDCODED_CREDS', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @provstr=N'DRIVER=SnowflakeDSIIDriver;SERVER=xyz12345.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com;UID=testuser;PWD=Testuser1';
 /*creds hardcoded in the connection string, logins use their own security context */
/* caveat: this worked ok for windows authenticated logins. sql authenticated logins could not use the linked server, not tested with msdasql in process... */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SNOWFLAKE_WITHOUT_DSN_HARDCODED_CREDS',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL;
*/
```

Comment: So if I have no mappings defined in the top section of the Security dialog and just put in the Snowflake remote login credentials after checking 'Be made using this security context', it should work? I'm still getting the same invalid credentials error. Oddly enough, I'm also seeing no files in the folder c:\users\my.name\Snowflake ODBC Driver\log. This, by the way, is Sql server 2014 in Windows server 2019

Comment: yes, that is the idea.
if you want to test your system dsn and the username&password without creating a linkedserver you could execute the following in ssms (Yourxxx  are self explanatory). If dsn&username&password are correct you should get a result or an error not related to datasource and authentication:

`
select *
from openrowset
   (  'MSDASQL'
     ,'dsn=YourDSNnamE;user_id=YourUsernamE;password=YourPassworD'
     ,'select * from information_schema.tables')
;`

Comment: the swonflake odbc provider expects a pwd, the following worked for me:
select *
from openrowset('MSDASQL', 'dsn=SNOWFLAKEDSN;uid=testuser;pwd=Testuser1', 'select cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar(100)) as tablename from demo_db.information_schema.tables')

Comment: edited the answer, added tsql for testing snowflake with openrowset and creating snowflake linked servers.

Comment: Well, that looks like the answer. I've got a different problem, now, but I don't think it's connectivity related. When I run the openrowset command (with my parameters) I now get: "Shared database is no longer available for use. It will need to be re-created if and when the publisher makes it available again.".

Comment: did you use the the query 'select...from demo_db.information_schema.tables' as it appears in the answer?  DEMO_DB, SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA, UTIL_DB are existing dbs when registering for a trial. you could try a dummy query like : openrowset(.....'select cast(1 as int) as test')