# I cannot authenticate user in SSMS for linked server (snowflake)

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ssms, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Similar problem to one reported here:
[Can't create linked server to Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145361/cant-create-linked-server-to-snowflake/69658174#69658174)

Difference is while connecting to snowflake I cannot authenticate user  in the SSMS:

[image]

ODBC driver must be verified by external browser (no password) but it is not happening here. Internet browser in SSMS is working fine, but it is not used to authenticate ODBC user. Configuration of ODBC is fine, as it is working in PowerBI and starting authentication process in default internet browser. Any ideas?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

> ODBC driver must be verified by external browser

Linked server connections run in the SQL Server process, so there's no interactive access to the desktop to do any kind of interactive authentication.

Comment: SQL serwer is working fine, i need to connect the Snowflake as linked server. How to validate the user if ODBC requires SAML validation?

Comment: It can't be done.  "SAML validation" is interactive with the desktop.  Linked server can't access the desktop.

Comment: ok, but how about creating local sql server on computer, that will link to snowflake, can this be done?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: start empty sql server on computer, just to utilize same desktop rights

Comment: You could try LocalDb, which is SQL Server running in your desktop session.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15 But there's probably a non-interactive way to connect to Snowflake.